# JPA: Get data from a one to one relationship

Tags: java, jpa

I have got two tables(models) in JPA as follows:

```
Table Employee|         | Table Person |
--------------|         ----------------
id            |         | id           |
mobile_number |         | employee_id  |
                        | address      |
```

I have got the mobile number and I need to know the address? How can this be done using JPA?

Since I am using JPA, do I still need to write a query that will join these two tables and then return me the result? (as when doing operations on a single table, JPA give you functions like getByid() or getBymobileNumber etc)

The entity bean:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date created;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastModified;

    private String mobileNumber;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date created;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastModified;

    @OneToOne
    private Employee employee;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the entity beans for Employee and Person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an entity by ID using `EntityManager.find()`. When looking for an entity using something other than its ID, then you must create a query.

To get the person referencing the employee having a given mobile number (assuming only one exists), the query would be

```
select p from Person p where p.employee.mobileNumber = :theMobileNumber
```

To get the address directly, the query would be

```
select p.address from Person p where p.employee.mobileNumber = :theMobileNumber
```